# Can I use skills untrained in HarnMaster 3e?

Tags: skills, harnmaster

In HarnMaster 3rd edition, can a character use a skill untrained? For instance, can a character with no experience with Fishing try and use the Fishing Skill?

Or if the skill is similar to another skill, can they use it? For example, can a character with Broadsword skill use another type of sword?

Answer (score 1):

Minimum EML (Example)
A player would normally have a minimum
EML 05 in Climbing. However, climbing an
ice cliff, with a broken arm, during a
blizzard is probably impossible, and the
GM may feel an EML of zero is justified.

Listed on Skills 2 page on the right.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).